# Can oauth2_proxy be used to implement an OpenID Connect RP?

Tags: oauth, openid-connect

I'm interested in implementing an OpenID Connect RP for a web application running behind nginx, potentially using oauth2_proxy. Does oauth2_proxy support this out of the box or will additional OpenID Connect features have to be added?

Comment: there's also this option: https://github.com/pingidentity/lua-resty-openidc/

Comment: thank you @HansZ. I really appreciate those options but I was having some trouble pulling in openresty.

Comment: I'd suggest that it is worth to solve those problems; it doesn't look like oauth2_proxy supports generic OpenID Connect but it tightly coupled to Google's implementation (as far as OIDC compliant providers is concerned). Perhaps you can file issues/questions with oauth2_proxy and openresty.

Answer (score 0):

oauth2_proxy has a pull request for OpenID Connect configuration discovery, but I was unable to make it work; it seemed like it wasn't getting valid json back from the https:// request. An alternative would be to code your provider's configuration in the same way that oauth2_proxy already supports Facebook and Google.

I'm not sure whether oauth2_proxy supports anything besides the authorization code flow; you get redirected to Google login, back to your server, and it sets an oauth2_proxy specific cookie to keep you logged back in to your own server.